# Ratio of two variables

Tags: matlab, variables

I am trying to find the ratio of two variables but am unsure how to do so. I would also like to separate the fraction into the real and imaginary terms. Below is my current script.

```
syms Vo ro RF s Cl Cgd Vi gme Rf

x=Vo*((1/ro)+(1/RF)+s*(Cl+Cgd));
y=Vi*(s*Cgd+(1/RF)-gme);
z = y==x;
```

I would like to find the ratio of Vo/Vi. I'm doing KCL for a circuit and would like to compare to my hand calculation to confirm I did it correctly.

Comment: Why do all of these need to be `syms` variables? Why is computing the ratio Vo/Vi not just as simple as `r = Vo/Vi`?

Comment: I don't know. That is why I asked. I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the ratio of `Vo` & `Vi`, a simple `Vo/Vi` is enough. While if you want to find the real and imaginary parts of the fraction, try this-

```
real(Vo/Vi) % real part of the fraction
imag(Vo/Vi) % imaginary part of the fraction
```